# How to fix the problem that objects regenerate after scene remake

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The goal I expected to achieve is that an object will be destroyed after being clicked, and the object that was just clicked will appear in the backpack, but the problem now is that when the object is destroyed, when I return to the same scene again, the destroyed object will appear again. Regenerates, which makes my players keep clicking and picking up the same objects countless times.

This is my current code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetItem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public item thisItem;
    public inventory playerBag;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        AddNewItem();
        Debug.Log(+1);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public void AddNewItem()
    {

        if (!playerBag.itemList.Contains(thisItem))
        {
            playerBag.itemList.Add(thisItem);
        }
        else
        {
            thisItem.itemHeld += 1;
        }
        inventorymanager.RefreshItem();
    }

  
}
```

This bug has troubled me for a long time, and I hope that a professional can answer this question，thanks.

Comment: It's not a bug, this is intended behavior. If you want objects to be removed permanently, you have to track their state across the application and whenever they spawn, they (or some kind of spawner) need to check if they should exist and if not, remove or do not spawn them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Make a spawner for your in-game objects, let it store a prefab of it and make it look like an object in Editor. Spawn objects on Start or on after whatever logic happens, track the spawn timings when the player is away from the map - attach regular c# object to each spawner to track its state, store those objects somewhere and update if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You could give each object a unique ID and keep track of them e.g. in `PlayerPrefs` or any more advanced database etc.

Then you simply check if the according ID already is known => destroy your object.

```
public class PickableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string _uniqueID;
```

#if UNITY_EDITOR
private void OnValidate()
{
if(PrefabUtility.IsPartOfAnyPrefab(this))
{
_uniqueID = null;
return;
}

```
        if(string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(_uniqueID))
        {
            _uniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        OnValidate();
    }
```

#endif

```
    // On spawn check if this ID was already picked up earlier
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey(_uniqueID))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Call this when you pick up the item so it is added to the "known" IDs
    public void PickUp()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(_uniqueID, 1);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

This is a very simple "dumb" example approach for getting IDs which might still cause conflicts, have issues with prefabs etc. There are more sophisticated solutions [like e.g. this one](https://github.com/ashblue/fluid-unique-id) - the principle stays the same

Comment: Using `PlayerPrefs` to store object state is not right. It is inteded for small inter-session persistent data. The best wat to store the state of object between scenes is a non-UnityEngine.Object state container which is stored in some collection (even a ScriptableObject fits well for this and easy to use) and is obtained when the object is spawned again.

Comment: @Xander ScriptableObject can not store any data cross-sections .. you will always need some external FileIO for this, PlayerPrefs **can** do this .. as mentioned `or any more advanced database etc.` would always be the more stable and secure approach of course .. but in the meantime `PlayerPrefs` works just as fine as any other local file serialization

Comment: I meant ScriptableObjects for cross-scene data persistence, for most of the features that's enough.